# Prevent sharing existing YouTube comments on Google+

Tags: youtube, google-plus

Whenever I make a comment on YouTube, it's shared on my Google+ profile for everyone to see my recent activities/comments. I've figured out how to prevent sharing in the future, but:

how can I make my previously made comments invisible on my Google+ profile?

Answer (score 1):

Delete them and create new comments that are not shared to Google+.

Comment: Currently there is no way to hide the existing comments in the Google+  so you can follow Abraham comments